# Web service Oath2 zend framework 1.12

Tags: web-services, zend-framework, oauth-2.0, box-api

I'm attempting to set up an authorization process through the Box-Api. The first step has to be a GET call to the authorization URL, It has to carry three parameters:

1. Redirect_url
2. Client_id
3. Response_type=Code

This is my sample code for this call:

```
 class OauthController extends Zend_Controller_Action
 {

public function indexAction() 
{
                $client = new Zend_Http_Client('https://www.box.com/api/oauth2/authorize');
        $client->setMethod(Zend_Http_Client::GET);
        $client->setParameterGet(array(
                'response_type'  => 'code',
                'client_id' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                'redirect_uri'     => 'http://localhost/imball-reagens/callback'
        ));
        $response = $client->request();
        $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
        return $response;
}

}
```

I've made a link in the homepage of my website to this controller, and i've taken away the view so the Controller can do only the http call. It should propt the user with the login of Box.com, but it doesn't, instead it only shows a white page. 
Zend server throws a warning when i call this controller:

```
 Slow Request Execution

 Request to http://localhost:10088/imball-reagens/public/oauth took 3042ms
```

Answer (score 0):

The procedure has to be written in a link in the homepage. This an example:

```
 <a href="https://www.box.com/api/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=xxxxxxxxx&redirect_uri=http://localhost/callback">Authorize Account Box API</a>
```